# awk to handle un formatted input

Tags: awk

Would like know how to handle below situation, sample input delimited by space and want to format as comma-separated output.
All the text in a line up until the first field starting with a digit should be considered as a single field in the output.  In the sample data, there are always 3 numeric fields at the end of a line; in the real data, there are 14 such fields.

Input.txt

```
mmm 4394850 4465411 2579770
xxx yyy 2155419 2178791 1516446
aaa bbb (incl. ccc) 14291585 14438704 6106341
U.U.(W) 6789781 6882021 5940226
nnn 7335050 7534302 2963345
```

Have tried the command below, but I know it is incomplete:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS =" "; OFS = ","} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6} ' Input.txt
```

Desired output:

```
mmm,4394850,4465411,2579770
xxx yyy,2155419,2178791,1516446
aaa bbb (incl. ccc),14291585,14438704,6106341
U.U.(W),6789781,6882021,5940226
nnn,7335050,7534302,2963345
```

Comment: There is no logic in your attempt that tries to deal handle the numerical fields differently. Is the input always of the same format? Are there always 3 numerical fields at the end of each line, for example?

Comment: Tom Fenech , there are 14 numerical fields at the end of each line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{match($0,/[0-9 ]+$/); print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) gensub(/ /,",","g",substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH))}' file
mmm,4394850,4465411,2579770
xxx yyy,2155419,2178791,1516446
aaa bbb (incl. ccc),14291585,14438704,6106341
U.U.(W),6789781,6882021,5940226
nnn,7335050,7534302,2963345
```

with other awks, save the 2nd substr() output in a var and use gsub():

```
awk '{match($0,/[0-9 ]+$/); digs=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); gsub(/ /,",",digs); print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) digs}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it's the last 3 columns that are numerical (as in your example):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)printf "%s%s",$i,(i<NF-3?OFS:(i<NF?",":ORS))}' file
```

Basically print each field followed by a space, comma or newline depending on the field number.

Comment: Tom Fenech , Thanks a lot  but above command is fail if the input line is  A & B 8399153 8530270 131117 Output is A,&,B,8399153,8530270,131117

Comment: I cannot reproduce that output using my code. Did you use the `BEGIN` block from your code or something?

Comment: Tom Fenech , ya i understand the issue , last column numerical field is not constant always like 14 fields , some of the the lines having 14 fields, some of them for 10 numerical fields etc

Answer (score 1):

Another awk

```
awk '$0=gensub(/ ([0-9]+)/,",\\1","g")' file


mmm,4394850,4465411,2579770
xxx yyy,2155419,2178791,1516446
aaa bbb (incl. ccc),14291585,14438704,6106341
U.U.(W),6789781,6882021,5940226
nnn,7335050,7534302,2963345
```